# Can I have a two dimensional array of different types?

Tags: c++

```
// create array
Date** dateList = new Date*[SIZE];

// populate array
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    dateList[i] = new Date[2];
    Date date;
    date.input();

    dateList[i][0] = date;

    int n = dateNum(date);
    dateList[i][1] = n;
}
```

I want to store a object of `Date` type in `dateList[i][0]` and an `int` in `dateList[i][1]`. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Array of unions which could be ub. ?

Comment: If you have well defined structure of what you want to store there then use `struct` with Date int pair, if you want to be able to mix then union.

Comment: if you can use boost use could try `[boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any/s02.html)`. create an array of `Any`s and then you can store what ever type you want(type erasure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Arrays are of one type only. That is also true for multidimensional arrays.

Read about structs or even higher data structures like `map` to achieve the dessired effect.

Answer (score 4):

No.

A single array must be of a single type.  If you want the elements to represent different types of data, then the element in the array needs to be some kind of base class (pointer), or possibly a discriminated type like a `variant`.

Comment: Maybe bit-fiddling can do int and float in same array but would be slow because of extra read/write functions. Of course very hard and inefficient in terms of memory space for bigger objects.

Comment: Also generally a bad idea.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik:  Doing this would almost certianly evoke Undefined Behavior.  If you allocate an `int`, you can't pretend that it's a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have an overwhelming reason to do otherwise, it sounds like you want a vector of structs:

```
struct whatever { 
    Date date;
    int n;

    whatever(Date const &d, int i) : date(d), n(i) {}    
};

std::vector<whatever> dates;

Date date;
date.input();

dates.push_back(whatever(date, datenum(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it. The most direct one is to use `union`s: put the types that you want to share in a single `union`, then use the member corresponding to the dimension's type in your code. However, this approach is also the most restrictive, because types with constructors / destructors cannot go into `union`s.

A more convenient way to do this is to build a one-dimensional array of `pair<Date,int>` objects, like this:

```
pair<Date,int>* dateList = new  pair<Date,int>[SIZE];

// populate array
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    Date date;
    date.input();
    int n = dateNum(date);

    dateList[i] = make_pair(date, n);
}
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout << "Date: " date[i].first << " ";
    cout << "Int: " date[i].second << endl;
}
```

This approach lets the compiler check your types much closer, giving you a more robust solution.